# GCP Cloud Composer - not able to create environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to create a default Cloud Composer environment, but after 50 minutes I always get:

```
code:  2    
   message:  "Composer Backend timed out. Currently running tasks are [stage: CP_COMPOSER_AGENT_RUNNING
description: "RPC Successful: Pull"
response_timestamp {
  seconds: 1536874828
  nanos: 429000000
}
```

I have tried several times to clean all IAM's, storage, disable and enable Cloud Storage API, but still the same error. I'm NOT able to create composer environments from none of other projects.

Ideas very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this error before when permissions were not correctly set or when they were modified:

Trying one of the following approaches could help:

1. Assign at least the Composer Worker role to the user who tries to create an environment.
2. Verify that the default Compute Engine service account has also the Worker role (like *****-compute@***seviceaccount.com).

Let us know your results.

Comment: Also check the region where you create the env.

Comment: Another thing to look at is whether you have the service accounts: `service-[PROJECT ID]@[SERVICE NAME].iam.gserviceaccount.com` for the Cloud Composer in your lAM with the proper Service Agent role. In my project someone deleted those and this error came up everytime I tried to update it. I've deactivated and reactivated the Composer API and they came back to the IAM, solving my issue.