# Unable to Create Composer Environment On GCP

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I created Composer Environment on GCP development environment with a service account that has the following permissions

- Composer Administrator
- Composer Worker
- Kubernetes Engine Admin
- Storage Object Admin
- BigQuery Admin
- Cloud SQL Admin

I was able to create the environment but If I try with exactly same permissions on production environment I get `Custom service accounts need correct permissions for environment creation to succeed.` as error after waiting for 50 mins.

I have also tried creating using Gcloud from client machine but that also didn't work out for me. I tried by disabling and re-enable the Composer API and created the environment again which also wasn't helpful. I have looked at following resources

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-composer-discuss/Jcrh8d2X3uU

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-composer-discuss/TnMDMq6Y-dU

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-composer-discuss/A1xU5eTL4fg

[GCP Cloud Composer - not able to create environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52322275/gcp-cloud-composer-not-able-to-create-environment)

Can someone tell me what permissions I need to create the Composer Environment.

Comment: Are there any differences between your development environment and your production environment? If you are sure that both service accounts have **exactly** the same permissions, then it's probably related to your production environment, since it works on the dev one. Could you try to create a brand new project, with only a service account with the same permissions, a Composer environment, and see if it works? Also, if that can "reassure" you, I've also experimented the 30+ mins delay even if it fails at the end...

Comment: I'm sure that the service account has exactly same permissions on both environments but I don't have much knowledge about the development and production environment differences.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following 2 things in your production environment:

1) **Domain Restricted Sharing** Organisation Policy is turned off when creating Cloud Composer. You can re-enable this org policy after the composer environment is created.

2) **VPC Service Controls** is turned off.

Composer doesn't work well if any one of the above is turned ON.

Comment: The difference I noticed was, I have composer Administrator on dev environment which I don't have on production environment. Could that be any issue?

Comment: No, the composer service account just needs "Composer Worker" IAM role

Comment: I have tried by changing the user permissions also which didn't help me. I don't have good understanding for **Domain Restricted Sharing** and **VPC Service Controls.** Could you please elaborate on how it effects in creating the Composer environment. Thanks!

Comment: More information on how **Domain Restricted Sharing** and **VPC Service Controls** affect Composer environment creation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/creating#access-control).

Answer (score 0):

When you create cloud composer environment , it crate pub/sub topic as well.
Please provide pub/sub admin role as well.